# How to disable <select> when there are no options returned from filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, html-select, disabled-control

I have something like this :

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="dataValidatorNewResource.name" 
        ng-options="dv.name for dv in dataValidators | filter:filterDataValidator">
</select>
```

I would like to know how to disable the whole select when the filter returns no option at all.

I tried this :

**JS**

```
      $scope.enableAddDataValidatorForm = true;
      $scope.filterDataValidator = function(v) {
        var found = false;

        // Do the filtering stuff...

        $scope.enableAddDataValidatorForm = !found; 
        return !found;
      }
```

then adding a `ng-disabled="!enableAddDataValidatorForm"` to the `<select>` but it doesn't work well. Besides, the filter is called very often and I would like to know if there is a more straight way to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable the `select` when the filter returns no option at all. So just do it!

```
<select
    ng-model="dataValidatorNewResource.name" 
    ng-options="dv.name for dv in dataValidators | filter:filterDataValidator"
    ng-disabled="(dataValidators | filter:filterDataValidator).length === 0"
>
</select>
```